# Trying to create a theme for blogspot using WYSIWYG web builder, it runs on https://www.w3schools.com/ but not on blogger HTML theme editor

Tags: html, css, templates, blogger

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wb_Text1" style="position:absolute;left:458px;top:19px;width:156px;height:16px;z-index:1;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">This is My First Post</span></div>
<div id="wb_Text2" style="position:absolute;left:338px;top:60px;width:509px;height:32px;z-index:2;">
<span style="color:#000000;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">If i am looking at it<br>that means i 
am able to create the theme correctly using webbuilder</span></div>
</body>
</html>
```

it runs perfectly
but fails to run on Blogger
What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code is perfect but, in blogger theme design with html you need to add "b:skin and b:section" inside that code.

And this is the sample code for blogger from your code :

Sorry if i wrong but thats all i know :)

---

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
<b:skin>
<!-- Your CSS Code Here -->
</b:skin>
</head>

<body>
<b:section id='Unique-Id'>
<!-- Your section content -->
</b:section>
```